Which Punctuation Best Introduces an Example in Formal Writing: Comma, Colon, or Hyphen?

The Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development (OECD) tracks comparative price list data for its thirty-eight member countries. According to this data, in July 2021, a “basket” of goods and services priced at 100 US dollars (USD) in the United States would have cost 80 USD in fellow OECD member ______.

Which choice completes the text so that it conforms to the conventions of Standard English?

A) nation-Spain.
B) nation, Spain.
C) nation Spain.
D) nation: Spain.

I’m trying to figure out which punctuation choice follows Standard English conventions. Here’s what I think so far:

Option A (nation-Spain): A hyphen doesn’t seem appropriate here because it’s not used to introduce examples or clarify terms.
Option B (nation, Spain): A comma is sometimes used, but I feel like this isn’t formal enough for the context.
Option C (nation Spain): No punctuation seems too informal and doesn’t conform to Standard English.
Option D (nation: Spain): The colon feels correct for formally introducing “Spain” as the specific OECD member.

I believe the correct answer is D (nation: Spain) because a colon is typically used to introduce a specific example in a sentence like this. Is there a better explanation for why this is the standard?

Just "in Spain" would be fine. We've already gathered that it's one of the 38 nations; that's why it has info on it.

I would actually choose C, as there's no reason to interrupt the sentence.

I'm wondering how you arrive at 'Option C (nation Spain): No punctuation seems too informal and doesn’t conform to Standard English.' Such statements need supporting evidence from a recognised authority (and note that even style guides, like CMoS, don't claim to define 'Standard English'. 'Standard English' itself has been discussed here before, and found to be a slippery notion. We haven't an Académie (and the French don't always respect the rulings of their own).
I'd have marked the colon (or a dash) down a mark; the comma I probably would have also downmarked, though some have argued for the 'opportunity to breathe (when reading aloud) after an over-long sentence' usage.
The reasons are that the colon and dash interrupt the running text far too abruptly, and the comma is also invasive, unnecessary, arguably always incorrect in a renaming / particularising appositive (compare 'Meet my sister Anne' [when you have three sisters]: a restrictive appositive, and the comma would be incorrect.)
A hyphen I might have deducted two marks for.

I do not think you can condemn the comma.  "I am commenting at a Stack Exchange site, English Language & Usage" looks reasonable to me.

The inclusion of 'a' certainly makes the comma necessary (not just reasonable). But "I am commenting at Stack Exchange site, English Language & Usage" doesn't look reasonable.
